# Show that this is a stopping time

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, stopping-times

Show that $\sigma=\inf \{ t\ge 0 : |B_t|= \log t \}$  is a stopping time with
respect to $(\mathcal F_t^B)_{t\ge0}$.

I've been trying to put the set $\{\sigma\le t\}$ equal to a countable union and then showing that this union belongs in $\mathcal F_t^B$. I am struggling to derive a countable union to this as I am only familiar with when $B_t$ is equal to a number and not a function of $t$.

***definitions***
$(\Omega,\mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ is a probability space.  $(\cal F_t)_{t \ge 0}$ is a stochastic basis: that is, for each real $t \ge 0$, $\mathcal F_t$ is a sigma-algebra contained in $\mathcal F$, and if $s \le t$ then $\mathcal F_s \subseteq \mathcal F_t$.  Perhaps we even assume the stochastic basis is *right-continuous*, namely
$$
\mathcal F_t = \bigcap_{s>t}\mathcal F_s
$$
for all $t$.  $(B_t)$ is a stochastic process adapted to $(\mathcal F_t)$: that is, for each $t$, $B_t : \Omega \to \mathbb R$ is a random variable, measurable with respect to $\mathcal F_t$.  Define random variable $\sigma$ as above, $\sigma :  \Omega \to [0,+\infty]$.  We want to show $\sigma$ is a *stopping time* for $(\mathcal F_t)$: that is, for every real $t$,
$$
\{\sigma \le t\} := \{\omega \in \Omega : \sigma(\omega) \le t\}
$$
belongs to $\mathcal F_t$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: If you wish to post the questions of your homework here, please add some personal input to them.

Comment: @user120678 : You shouldn't write here in a style appropriate for instructors assigning homework, saying "Prove this.", etc.  Sometimes that means the poster is just doing stenography, passing on to us a question written by someone else, without showing any sign of having understood the question.

Comment: What is a stopping time?

Comment: added definitions.  Anyone who doesn't know what is a stopping time, should of course skip this question.

Comment: How would i show this is in $F_t$?

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
$$[\sigma\leqslant t]=\bigcup_{r\in\mathbb Q,r\leqslant t}[|B_r|=\log r]$$
Of course, to see why this identity holds is part of the fun...

Comment: My justification of your hint is correct yes?

Comment: @YinPeiTo Why are you copying my post?

Comment: Attempting to add more details to it. Is my justification correct?

Comment: @YinPeiTo Since you (chose to) fail(ed) to get the point the first time, let me reiterate: to essentially copy an existing answer, pretending it is "incomplete" or that it needs "justification", is not ethical.

Answer (score -3):

Recall that a random variable $\tau : \Omega \to [0, \infty]$ is a stopping time with respect to the filtration $(\mathscr{F}_t)_{t \geq0 }$ if $\{ \tau \leq t \} \in \mathscr{F}_t$ for all $t \geq 0$. Therefore, to see that $\tau = \inf \{ t \geq 0 : \left| B_t \right| = \log t \}$ is a stopping time, consider that \begin{eqnarray*}
\{ \tau \leq t \} &=& \bigcap_{0 \leq s \leq t} \{ \omega : \left| B_s(\omega) \right| = \log s \} \\
&=& \bigcup_{s \in [0,t] \cap \mathbb{Q}} \{ \omega : \left| B_s(\omega) \right| = \log s \}, 
\end{eqnarray*} where the last equality follows from the right-continuity of the Brownian motion and the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Now the sets $\{ \omega : \left| B_s(\omega) \right| = \log s \}$ are all $\mathscr{F}_s$-measurable, for $s \leq t$. Moreover, since the filtration is increasing, these sets are all $\mathscr{F}_t$-measurable. Since we have a countable union of $\mathscr{F}_t$-measurable sets, it follows that $\{ \tau \leq t \} \in \mathscr{F}_t$ and $\tau$ is a stopping time.