# Showing that $\tau=\inf\{t\ge0:M_t\le\epsilon\}$ is a stopping time, where $M_t=M_0e^{W_t-t/2}$

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, stopping-times

> Let $(W_t,\mathscr{F_t})$ be a Wiener process and let
>   $$M_t=M_0e^{W_t-t/2}\qquad t\ge0$$
>   where $M_0$ is deterministic.
>   Show that, for $\epsilon>0$,  $\tau=\inf\{t\ge0:M_t\le\epsilon\}$ is a stopping time.

I have been able to show that $M_t$ is a martingale but I'm a bit stuck here. I tried to use the fact that $W_t$ is a normal distribution to show that $P(M_t<\epsilon)>0$ but that got me no where.

Comment: How is any of what you explain related to the question of knowing whether $\tau$ is a stopping time?

Comment: Sorry I'm am a bit confused by what you are asking.

Comment: Really? Let me retry: the question is "Show that tau is a stopping time." And right after stating the question, you mention that you "have been able to show that M is a martingale". OK, nice to know, but why did you even try to prove the latter (M is a martingale) when asked the former (tau is a stopping time)? Likewise, why turn to proving or disproving that  $P(M_t<\epsilon)>0$ when, once again, your aim is to show that tau is a stopping time. Say, do you remember the definition of being a stopping time?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/635171/

Comment: Ok yes showing that M is a martingale is irrelevant as it was part of a previous question and thought it might be helpful in solving the question. From my understanding the stopping time is a time that belongs to $F_t$. Just not sure how to go about in proving something is a stopping time in general. Will check out the link. Thank you for your help. Will do my best

Comment: "From my understanding the stopping time is a time that belongs to Ft" No. This confirms you need first and foremost to check the definition of a stopping time.

Comment: I have been spending some time reading different definitions and I'm still a bit confused. From what i can see, it is a random variable of the time where the event/stopping rule occurs which has to belong to Ft. tau = {w : tau(w) < t } belongs to Ft. To prove that tau is a stopping time, do we use sets?

Comment: An example I can across is if you are driving along a road and need to find parking. If you were looking for the last free spot on the road this wouldn't be a stopping time, as this requires future information which can't be the case as you can only use information up until t. Let say that the stopping time is the first free space you come across. If we have driven for some time t but we still haven't come across a free spot, would this still be considered a stopping time even though the stopping rule hasn't been satisfied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. Prove that $$\omega \mapsto \inf_{s \leq t} M_s(\omega)$$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable. To this end, use the continuity of the sample paths of the Wiener process to show that $$\inf_{s \leq t} M_s(\omega) = \inf_{\substack{s \leq t \\ s \in \mathbb{Q}}} M_s(\omega).$$
2. Show that $$\{\tau \leq t\} = \left\{ \inf_{s \leq t} M_s \leq \epsilon \right\}.$$
3. Conclude.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that a random variable $\tau : \Omega \to [0,\infty]$ is called a stopping time with respect to the filtration $(\mathscr{F}_t)_{t \geq 0}$ if $\{ \tau \leq t \} \in \mathscr{F}_t$ for any $t \geq 0$. To this end, let us observe that \begin{eqnarray}
\{ \tau \leq t \} &=& \{ \omega \in \mathbb{R} : M_t(\omega) \leq \varepsilon \} \nonumber \\
&=& \bigcup_{0 \leq s \leq t} \{ \omega \in \mathbb{R} : M_s(\omega) \leq \varepsilon \} \nonumber \\
&=& \bigcup_{s \in [0,t] \cap \mathbb{Q}} \{ \omega \in \mathbb{R} : M_s(\omega) \leq \varepsilon \}, 
\end{eqnarray} where (1) follows from the fact that for each $s \in [0,t]$, $M_s(\omega)$ is continuous. Now the sets $\{ \omega \in \mathbb{R} : M_s(\omega) \leq \varepsilon \}$ are all $\mathscr{F}_s$-measurable. Since the filtration is increasing, this implies that these sets are $\mathscr{F}_t$-measurable also. Thus, since we have a countable union of $\mathscr{F}_t$-measurable sets, it follows that $\{ \tau \leq t \} \in \mathscr{F}_t$ and so $\tau$ is a stopping time.